# saving related data with meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This is probably a dumb question but I've been everywhere (official docs, discover meteor, SO, several blogs...) and I just can't sort this out. Part of the problem is probably because I'm very used to relational dbs and I could be wrong about MongoDB ways of work and I don't know how to approach this.

Anyway, I'm writing a test application as an exercise to learn something about meteor and I'm stuck in trying to save an array of tags related to a single item. I know how to save plain data:

```
Tasks.insert({
  text: text,
  createdAt: new Date(),
  owner: Meteor.userId(),
  username: Meteor.user().username
});
```

how do I save a related list of tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just save the array.

```
tags = ['hot', 'spicy', 'green']
Tasks.insert({
  tags: tags,
  text: text,
  createdAt: new Date(),
  owner: Meteor.userId(),
  username: Meteor.user().username
});
```